# How to edit using ViewData model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a View Model based on combination of three Tables.

I click on Edit action it displays the Data from Three tables correctly.

But when i click  on Save button i am not able to get data either from FormCollection or from Request["Id"]

Please suggest it the possible way.

public class ConferenceResourceEditModel
    {

```
    public ConferenceRoom ConferenceRoom { get; set; }

    public Resources Resources { get; set; }

    public ResourceAllocation ResourceAllocation { get; set; }

}
```

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
 {

//ConferenceRoom conferenceroom = db.ConferenceRooms.Find(id);

```
        var query =

               from c in db.ConferenceRooms

               from r in db.Resourcess

               from ra in db.ResourceAllocation

               where c.ConferenceID == id


               where c.ConferenceID == ra.ConferenceID 

               where r.ResourceID ==ra.ResourceID 

               select new ConferenceResourceEditModel { ConferenceRoom = c, Resources = r,ResourceAllocation=ra };

        return View(query);       
    }

    //
    // POST: /ConferenceRoom/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form, int id, ConferenceResourceEditModel conferenceroom,ConferenceRoom crf)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(conferenceroom).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(conferenceroom);
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Please do suggest the ways of Getting the Value from FormCollection as its showing Blank one

Answer (score 0):

Look up model binding on the http://www.asp.net/mvc site where there are magnificent tutorials about this kind of thing.

in a nutshell your controller action will take a parameter of type YOURVIEWMODEL and bind to it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use some ORM ( like [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ff714342.aspx),personally i recommend [DatabaseFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx) approach). Using something like that:

var query =

```
           from c in db.ConferenceRooms

           from r in db.Resourcess

           from ra in db.ResourceAllocation

           where c.ConferenceID == id


           where c.ConferenceID == ra.ConferenceID 

           where r.ResourceID ==ra.ResourceID
```

is much more complicated and difficult. Hope it will help.

Comment: With above scenario is it possible to Get the values in formCollection or Viewdatamodel

Comment: Of course. Look here: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/aspdotnet-mvc3-intro , especially "Working with Data in ASP.NET MVC 3" part. Great explanation,how to create good controller/view workflow using ORM